# How can I make my main program appear first and how can I call my functions in my main program?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, program-entry-point, subroutine

Right now I've tried making my main program the main "function" in my code. But when I run it, the analysis bit comes up first which is not what i want. I want to make my code to do the following: output the main program so the user can input the marks total and input the marks scored in a test.

"Write a program that inputs a mark from the keyboard for sections of a project: ‘analysis’, ‘design’,
‘implementation’ and ‘evaluation’. The program should output the total mark, the grade, and how many
more marks were needed to get into the next mark band."

That was my task.

```
    def analysis():
        print("Welcome to the analysis section")
        marktotal=int(input("Input mark total which is out of /100"))
        marks=int(input("Input marks"))
        totalanalysis=print("You got",marks,"/",marktotal)
        if marks > 80 or marks == 80:
            print("A*")
        elif marks > 67 or marks == 67:
            print("A")
        elif marks > 54 or marks == 54:
            print("B")
        elif marks > 41 or marks == 41:
            print("C")
        elif marks > 31 or marks == 31:
            print("D")
        elif marks > 22 or marks == 22:
            print("E")
        elif marks > 13 or marks == 13:
            print("F")
        elif marks > 4 or marks == 4:
            print("G")
        elif marks ==0:
            print("U")
        return
    analysis()

    def design():
        print("Welcome to the design section")
        marktotal=int(input("Input mark total which is out of /100"))
        marks=int(input("Input marks"))
        totalanalysis=print("You got",marks,"/",marktotal)
        return

    design()


    def main():
        selectedsection=str(input("What section would you like to grade?"))#main program starts here
        if selectedsection =="analysis":
            analysis()
        elif selectedsection =="design":
            print("design")
        elif selectedsection =="implementation":
             print("implementation")
        elif selectedsection =="evaluation":
             print("evaluation")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the analysis function comes up before the main program which is what I want to come up first but it doesn't.

Comment: don't call `analysis` before `design`?

Comment: Also notice that in your `main` you are doing `print("design")` when you probably meant to do `design()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the functions, remove `analysis()` and `design()` from your  code  outside main function.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your code and made some changes so that it is working.
I hope this helps you to find your problem.

The part around your

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

looks strange. The main() function should be on its own line.
Your posted code also had some indentation problems and the closing backticks should not be shown at the end. I cannot change your post, because I have not enough reputation for that.
The  occurence of the function calls "analysis(), design() and main()" seem weird.
I have deleted analysis() and design(). Also I have moved main() to its own line. Hard to say, if your original code is exactly the same as the posted code.

```
def analysis():
    print("Welcome to the analysis section")
    marktotal=int(input("Input mark total which is out of /100"))
    marks=int(input("Input marks"))
    totalanalysis=print("You got",marks,"/",marktotal)
    if marks > 80 or marks == 80:
        print("A*")
    elif marks > 67 or marks == 67:
        print("A")
    elif marks > 54 or marks == 54:
        print("B")
    elif marks > 41 or marks == 41:
        print("C")
    elif marks > 31 or marks == 31:
        print("D")
    elif marks > 22 or marks == 22:
        print("E")
    elif marks > 13 or marks == 13:
        print("F")
    elif marks > 4 or marks == 4:
        print("G")
    elif marks ==0:
        print("U")
    return

def design():
    print("Welcome to the design section")
    marktotal=int(input("Input mark total which is out of /100"))
    marks=int(input("Input marks"))
    totalanalysis=print("You got",marks,"/",marktotal)
    return

def main():
    selectedsection=str(input("What section would you like to grade?"))#main program starts here
    if selectedsection =="analysis":
        analysis()
    elif selectedsection =="design":
        print("design")
    elif selectedsection =="implementation":
        print("implementation")
    elif selectedsection =="evaluation":
        print("evaluation")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```